# RewriteRule + HTTPS redirect for specific requests

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, https

I have setup the `htaccess` file to handle users requests with a specific rule and generic requests with other rules:

```
# users requests (i.e. users/login.html)
RewriteRule ^users/([^/]+)\.html$ mvc.php?rt=users/$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# generic requests (controller/action/id.html)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ mvc.php?rt=$1/$2&id=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

# generic requests (controller/action/)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ mvc.php?rt=$1/$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# generic requests (controller/id.html)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ mvc.php?rt=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# generic requests (controller.html)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)\.html$ mvc.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^$ mvc.php?rt=index [L,QSA,NC]
```

This works fine, and URL translation is handled correctly. My goal is now to force all users requests to be sent over HTTPS. I'm trying to setup a redirect rule as described in [RewriteHTTPToHTTPS](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS). I know this is not the recomended solution, but my server doesn't seem to support `VirtualHost` statements. Here is my code:

```
# users http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^users(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/users$1 [R,L]
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work because I needed to insert the `L` flag after all rules, which causes the processing to stop when the rule is met. So, if the http-to-https rule is inserted first in `htaccess`, this rule is met and user specific rule is ignored (and viceversa for other case).
 Is there a way to both:

1. handle users requests with a specific rule
2. force users requests to be sent over HTTPS

with `htaccess` rules?

Comment: Why do you want to redirect only certain request to https ? You know it's insecure and do not protect against MITM+sslstrip ? (The only protection is to use https for the whole domain and activate HSTS)

Comment: @Tom: actually, I supposed that protecting pages with sensible data (such as users pages) was sufficient. Also, thought that forcing common pages (such as terms and conditions page) to be sent over HTTPS was useless. But I wasn't aware about issues you've pointed out. So your advice is to force all request to be over HTTPS via htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many reasons my advice is to :
- do 301 redirect to https on all http requests
- use [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) on all https answer

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

or

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerAlias *
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [redirect=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

And in the 443 Virtualhost : 
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"

WARNING : Set the Strict-Transport-Security ONLY when the https works on all webpage. You can try with 3600 (10 minutes) in the begining if you are not sure. The "includeSubDomains" will for https for all subdomains and "preload" will allow your website to be added to the preload list of browsers.

If you have a login page do not forget the Secure attribute on the cookies (without it the cookie will be sent with insecure http request too).

Why ?
- Because without HSTS someone can force the browser to do a request to http://example.com/mysecurepage and then intercept the http request before you answer a 301, and respond the same page than the one you respond, but with http links instead. This attack is called sslstrip and the only thing that can prevent it is HSTS ([preloaded](https://hstspreload.appspot.com/) if possible)
- With HSTS protect you if you forgot to add the secure attribute on cookies (but not all browser know HSTS, that's why it's still important to use the secure attribute!)
- Because it's easy to miss which pages must be mark secure : 
 if a page ask for personal data (email, name, ...) then in most European country you have the obligation to secure it ; sometimes, a page do not ask personal data but display it ; sometime the fact that the content of the page is public do not mean the visitor accept that anyone know he visits it.
- With HTTP2 and SPDY encrypted page can be served faster than not encrypted one: https://istlsfastyet.com/

Comment: Very clear explanation, +1 for that. Unfortunately, the server I'm working on doesn't seem to support VirtualHost statement (when I add it in htaccess, I get a 500 internal server error). Plus, it doesn't support HSTS too. Is there a way to increase connection security, even without these importants points? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Giorgio I've updated the answer for the case without VirtualHost. When you say your server doesn't support HSTS, you mean you can't set headers ?

Comment: It's only a deduction. I suppose it doesn't support HSTS because I've done some search in my provider configuration/help pages and I haven't found anything talking about HSTS. Is there some way I can check if HSTS is actually supported in my server? Thanks and sorry for the slight OT.

Comment: @Giorgio it doesn't have to support HSTS specifically: if you can set custom headers, then it support HSTS :)

Comment: Ok now I got it. Just a last precisation: since I'm using your first snippet (without VirtualHost) I can't include the `Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"` statement in the 443 Virtualhost code block. So I've added it just after the https RewriteRule. Is it correct?